# Append top-aligned text to the bottom of a row of bottom-aligned images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a row of images that looks something like this:

```
[Image] [Image] [Image] [Image]
```

The images containers each have div class `".image` and each image container has a unique id (ie `"#image1"`, `"#image2"`, etc). The CSS looks like this:

```
.image {
      vertical-align: bottom;
      min-height: auto;
      min-width: auto;
      max-width: 126px;
    }
```

Through jQuery, I'm successfully able to append text below the individual images, i.e:

```
$("#image1").append("my text");
```

This code is in a loop, so the content of the text varies per image id. So the outcome looks like this:

```
                [Image]
                some
[Image] [Image] long    [Image]
my text my text text    my text
```

The problem is, when the text string is longer, it pushes the image up. I need it to look exactly like this:

```
[Image] [Image] [Image] [Image]
my text my text some    my text
                long
                text
```

Is there any way to achieve this? It looks like the text I'm appending adheres to the .image CSS rules and is bottom aligning the text as well. What I need is bottom-alined images and top-aligned text placed at the bottom of the images.

Update: here's what my HTML looks like:

```
<ol>
<li class=“image” id=“image1”>
    <a href=“mylink1.com”>
        <img src=“/my/image1/source”>
    </a>
    my text
</li>
<li class=“image” id=“image2”>
    <a href=“mylink2.com”>
        <img src=“/my/image2/source”>
    </a>
    my text
</li>
<li class=“image” id=“image3”>
    <a href=“mylink3.com”>
        <img src=“/my/image3/source”>
    </a>
    some long text
</li>
<li class=“image” id=“image4”>
    <a href=“mylink4.com”>
        <img src=“/my/image4/source”>
    </a>
    my text
</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use : `vertical-align: top;` on image div's:

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $images = $(".image");
  var text = ["smal text", "large textdslndsfj dsnfjsdnfkjdsfk jdsfjdsbfkj sbdfjkds", "small", "s"];
  $.each($images, function(index, value) {
    $(this).append(text[index]);
  })
})
```

```css
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png" />
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/579210574661328897/NcZmjtOw.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Wikibooks-logo-es.svg/400px-Wikibooks-logo-es.svg.png" />
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/iyjJLmHzdffIPboi3lEY2-3D5BXNcApoBZVgWJPZvC0K6xSzW6f8ewEbl7VPjM3kiOM=w300" />
</div>
```

Comment: The problem here is that I still need the image divs to be bottom aligned within their containers. So if the images have different heights, the tops will stagger and the bottoms will align, if that makes sense.

Comment: @FionaCat86 : Can you confirm is your HTML structure similar to what I have created in snippet?

Comment: ., I've updated the original post with what my HTML looks like--it looks similar in structure to what you have in the snippet.